# CSS Grid how to align variable height row content

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I have a two rows and 4 columns structure having a variable-length string in them. With the auto-rows enabled, the rows can stretch to justify the content. I have a button and the end of each grid, which I would like to align to the bottom of the grids. Can someone help me If it can be achieved easily with css grid?

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #BBB;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0 0 .75em 0;
}


/* first example */

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(250px, auto);
}

.card {
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 1em;
}

.grid {
  display: grid
}
```

```html
<!-- first example -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    </p>
    <p class="grid"><button> Submit Me!</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it.
    </p>
    <p class="grid"><button> Submit Me!</button></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum

    </p>
    <p class="grid"><button> Submit Me!</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>

    <p class="grid"><button> Submit Me!</button></p>

  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type.

    </p>
    <p class="grid"><button> Submit Me!</button></p>

  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    </p>
    <p class="grid"><button> Submit Me!</button></p>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambledh the release of Letraset sheets containing
      Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    </p>
    <p class="grid">
      <button> Submit Me!</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CodePen:
https://codepen.io/awaisdar001/pen/wvKaEvx

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
.card {
    border-right: 2px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    padding: 1em;

    /* new */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between; /* pins flex items to opposite ends */
}
```

This also works:

```
.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.grid {
    margin-top: auto; /* "pushes" flex item from the top, pinning it to the bottom */
}
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/Figueroa5566/pen/RwWPmxz)